# A MORE Odd Test Coverage Issue with an Inner Abstract Class and an Inner Extended Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am having some trouble getting *any* code coverage from my Test class. I noticed on the forum that there seemed to be an issue in regards to inner classes, which led me to a similar issue below:

[A Similar Issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7696/weird-issue-with-inner-class-not-being-covered-via-test-class)

However, I am using an inner abstract class and with that abstract class, extending it and creating a concrete class. Once I run my test, it gives me **Zero %** code coverage. Needless to say, this is quite an agitating issue.

**Diagnostic Code**

```
public with sharing class DiagnosticsInstrumentation 
{
    public abstract class BaseDiagnostics
    {
        private Boolean DiagnosticsEnabled;

        private List DiagnosticLog;

        public abstract void Push(String FunctionName);
        public abstract void Pop();
        public abstract void PopAll();
        public abstract void DiagnoseException(Exception DiagnosedException);

        private abstract String CurrentLog();
        private abstract void Diagnose(String DaignosticStatement);
        private abstract Boolean IsEnabled();

        public BaseDiagnostics()
        {
            this.DiagnosticsEnabled = this.IsEnabled();
            this.DiagnosticLog = new List();
        }
    }

    public class DiagnosticEntry
    {
        //...

        public DiagnosticEntry(String EntryDescription, Integer LevelNumber)
        {
            //...
        }
    }

    public class BasicDiagnostics extends BaseDiagnostics
    {
        public override void Push(String FunctionName)
        {
            //...
        }

        public override void Pop()
        {
            //...
        }

        public override void PopAll()
        {
            //...
        }

        public override void DiagnoseException(Exception DiagnosedException)
        {
            //...
        }

        private override String CurrentLog()
        {
            //...

            return null;
        }

        private override void Diagnose(String DiagnosticStatement)
        {
            //...
        }

        private override Boolean IsEnabled()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Diagnostic Code's Test Class**

*Note: In the test I added the **static** part but, if you add or remove it it makes no difference.*

```
@isTest
public with sharing class BasicDiagnostics_Tests 
{
    static 
    {
        new DiagnosticsInstrumentation();
    }

    public static TestMethod void Test_BasicDiagnostics_Functionality()
    {
        DiagnosticsInstrumentation.BaseDiagnostics TestDiagnosticTool = new DiagnosticsInstrumentation.BasicDiagnostics();

        TestDiagnosticTool.Push('Testing One Input');
        TestDiagnosticTool.Pop();

        TestDiagnosticTool.Push('Testing Two Input');
        TestDiagnosticTool.Push('Testing Three Input');
        TestDiagnosticTool.Push('Testing Four Input');

        TestDiagnosticTool.PopAll();

        Account NullAccount = new Account();

        try
        {
            INSERT NullAccount;
        }
        catch(DmlException Caught)
        {
            TestDiagnosticTool.DiagnoseException(Caught);
            TestDiagnosticTool.PopAll();
        }
    }
}
```

I thank anyone in advance for your help on this issue.

Comment: How are you running the tests? Sometimes I've seen a 0% after running, and then I just run again and it magically appears. I think there's some caching of results that can get a bit messed up from time to time.

Comment: I have run the test multiple times in the Eclipse IDE with the Force.com Plug-in, Developer Console, and through the setup menu. All still produce zero code coverage.

Comment: I'm thinking it could be related to the abstract class that's being used. If you add a constructor to BasicDiagnostics does that get covered?

Comment: I went ahead and tried that - still no results :-\ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, oddly enough, adding the constructor to the base class was the trick to having the Test class pass. However, it didn't pass *until* I ran it through the setup menu. ::shurgs:: Such a simple answer to a stubborn problem.

Comment: For some reason, although the code coverage _is_ being met (finally), it _**only**_ works when you run it through the setup menu. It does not give any code coverage through the Eclipse IDE **or** the Developer Console. Just keeping that in mind.

Comment: **Big Update** : Today I was running my tests through the IDE and it showed that it covered my classes within the Code Coverage window. I _also_ removed the empty constructor and it still worked! I suppose enough people either complained or someone was listening ::looks around::.