# My test classes are contributing towards uncovered code

Tags: webservices, unit-test, httpcalloutmock, webservicemock

I have a test class containing several `WebServiceMock` implementors. He looks like this:

```
@isTest private class MyTestClass {

    public class ValidateMock implements WebServiceMock {
        public void doInvoke(Object stub, Object request, Map<String, Object> response, String endpoint, String soapAction, String requestName, String responseNS, String responseName, String responseType) {
            //...
        }
    }

    static testMethod void coverRetrieve() {
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new ValidateMock());
        //...
        System.assert(result instanceof Object);
    }
}
```

But as I create more WebServiceMocks, I see the Code Coverage metrics for my org going south!

Of course, I tried to annotate the WebServiceMock inner classes with `@isTest` but will get:

> Only static top-level class methods can be test methods

(Which they should be, anyway, as inner classes of an `@IsTest` annotated class)

Currently I think my options are:

1. write a "Test Test" method that invokes all the mocks just to bump the coverage,
2. proliferate all the WebServiceMock classes as top-level, then add the `@isTest` annotation,

How else could I prevent these test inner classes being seen by the code coverage metrics?

Comment: I really think your second option is the best. That's the way I usually go. You may end up with a lot of files, but that seems better than cluttering up the code with "test test" methods.

Comment: Wonder if [this fixed known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Rle5AAC) is related? In that issue the inner class is in the code being tested and not the unit test code, but could be the same.  Could be a regression. Also [found this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7696/weird-issue-with-inner-class-not-being-covered-via-test-class).

Answer (score 1):

Found a combination that works:

- use `@TestVisible` *and* `private` visibility

This excludes it from code coverage metrics.

Comment: sometimes I use a constructor with args in my mock inner class so I don't have to write many mocks - rather, one mock adjusts its results using the 'settings' passed into the constructor. Another approach is to pass in a string of a static resource that contains the results you want from the callout so you only need one mock class and all the variability of response comes from staticresources